# How can we pass ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to sql server stored procedure using java?

Tags: java, sql-server

Here is my code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> collection=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();;
ArrayList<String> listOfSomething= new ArrayList<String>();;
listOfSomething.add("first");
listOfSomething.add("second");
collection.add(listOfSomething);
listOfSomething.add("third");
listOfSomething.add("fourth");
collection.add(listOfSomething);
String user="Test";

Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://....");
CallableStatement stmt= conn.prepareCall("{Call UserDatils(?,?,?)}");
stmt.setString(2, user);
stmt.setObject(3, collection.toString());
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql,Types.VARCHAR);
stmt.execute();
```

When I run above code it is giving an error called "Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible.."

I hope the issue is with this line

```
stmt.setObject(3, collection.toString());
```

Please let me know how can we pass this arraylist to stored procedure?

Thank you.

Comment: Please let me know the way to pass arralist<arraylst<string>>

Comment: What happens when you execute the SP directly in SSMS using the result of the `collection.toString()`?

Comment: It might also be helpful if you include your stored procedure because the exception you're receiving is SQL Server based

Comment: It would be ideal to pass the data as either XML or data table to the stored procedure.